# Resolved - Curved progress bar on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm having a hard time trying to create this design:
[curved progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOEPi.png)

anyone knows how to create this type of progress bar?

I started with some Canvas and that hard stuff but I really don't really know how to do it

edit: I had to trim the path by computing the metrics and create a new path to the active curve. I got the code from the [trimPath](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_drawing/latest/path_drawing/trimPath.html):

```
 class ShapePainter extends CustomPainter {
    final double value;
    final double total;
  
    ShapePainter({required this.value, required this.total});
  
    @override
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
      const backgroundColor = Color(0xFFFFEEE9);
      const activeColor = Color(0xFFFF8875);
  
      var backgroundPaint = createPaint(backgroundColor);
      var activePaint = createPaint(activeColor);
  
      var startPoint = Offset(0, size.height / 2);
      var endPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height / 2);
  
      // This control points help the bezier curve
      var controlPoint1 = Offset(size.width / 4, size.height);
      var controlPoint2 = Offset(3 * size.width / 4, size.height);
  
      var path = Path();
  
      // Move draw to start point
      path.moveTo(startPoint.dx, startPoint.dy);
  
      // Move draw to end point making the bezier curve
      path.cubicTo(controlPoint1.dx, controlPoint1.dy, controlPoint2.dx,
          controlPoint2.dy, endPoint.dx, endPoint.dy);
  
      canvas.drawPath(path, backgroundPaint);
  
      path = trimPath(path, value/total);
      canvas.drawPath(path, activePaint);
  
    }
  
    createPaint(color){
      // Set style to paint
      return Paint()
        ..color = color
        ..strokeWidth = 5
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    }
  
    Path trimPath(
        Path source,
        double percentage) {
      final Path dest = Path();
      for (final PathMetric metric in source.computeMetrics()) {
        dest.addPath(
          metric.extractPath(0.0, metric.length * percentage),
          Offset.zero,
        );
      }
  
      return dest;
    }
  
    @override
    bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
      // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: post your `CustomPainter` code then

Comment: a hint: you need [drawArc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/drawArc.html)

Comment: i'm not able to create a bezier curve with drawArc, but it seems the perfect function